# Why can't I import this Groovy library in Grails?

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm creating a service class in grails that generates a JSON structure and uses it to do a REST call to another service. I'm trying to import some `groovy.json` classes as follows:

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

class SomeService {
  ...
}
```

But, I'm get the following error:

```
1: unable to resolve class groovy.json.JsonBuilder
  [groovyc]  @ line 1, column 1.
  [groovyc]    import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
  [groovyc]    ^
```

When I try in groovysh, it seems to import these classes just fine. What do I need to do to pull in the standard Groovy JSON library in Grails?

Comment: Yea, what Burt said.  I can import and use them just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That class was introduced in Groovy 1.8 which isn't used in Grails until 2.0.0+. You'll need to either upgrade to 2.0.x+ or use a different JSON library.

Comment: Ugh... I didn't even think about checking the when those classes were created. Thanks Burt! I'm going to upgrade at some point in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you cannot import those classes, though I'm not sure you actually need them.  If your just trying to generate JSON then it is probably easiest to create a Groovy map then `render myMap as JSON`, which is available when you `import grails.converters.JSON`.

[grails.converters.JSON](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.4/api/grails/converters/JSON.html) equivilent to [groovy.json.JsonOutput](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/json/JsonOutput.html)

[grails.web.JSONBuilder](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.4/api/index.html?grails/web/JSONBuilder.html) equivilent to [groovy.json.JsonBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/index.html?groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html)